# Help with division layout

Tags: macros, math-operators

I would like to automate a division question in the layout as shown below, I have tried to alter the longdivision package but I would like it to have the crossed out numbers instead of the working below the sum.

[image: screenshot]

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
 \usepackage{longdivision}

 \usepackage{cancel}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \newcommand\Ccancel[2][black]{\renewcommand\CancelColor{\color{#1}}\cancel{#2}}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{cccc}
 0&5&&56&\

 $3 \overline{)168}$
 &
 $3 \overline{)\Ccancel
 [red]{1}{^1}68}$
 &
 &
 $3 \overline{)\Ccancel[red]{1}{{^1}\Ccancel[red]{6}{^1}}}8$\
 \end{tabular}

 \begin{tabular}{cccc}
 0&5&&56$^{^r1}$&\

 $3 \overline{)169}$
 &
 $3 \overline{)\Ccancel
 [red]{1}{^1}68
 9}$
 &
 &
 $3 \overline{)\Ccancel[red]{1}{{^1}\Ccancel[red]{6}{^1}}}9$\
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't know, if the screenshot shows what you have in mind. // Why don't you use \frac{}{} and one of the strike-through packages from ctan?

Comment: Thanks it was creating random sums with the strike though that I was after. but thank you I will look at using fractions instead of tables.